# Ubuntu + Install Redmine 1.2.1, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.11 Using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, redmine

Best way to Install `Redmine 1.2.1, RUBY 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.11, Rack 1.1.1, GitHub,` Using `RVM`

Can anyone suggest me the best way in which ,I follow to install it properly, because previously I felt in various dependencies issues.

Suggest something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going about it like this:

1. Install RVM - see https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ for details on that.
2. Install Ruby 1.8.7: `rvm install 1.8.7`
3. Actually use Ruby 1.8.7: `rvm use 1.8.7` (Add the flag --default to use 1.8.7 by default in every new terminal you open up)
4. Install Rails, Rack

   `gem install rails -v 2.3.11`

   `gem install rack -v 1.1.1`
5. Follow the rest of the installation procedure - http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall - including getting your database set up, modifying config files, etc etc.

After that, you shouldn't have any dependency issues, unless you've already got ruby 1.8.7 installed and a bunch of gems installed with it.  If that's the case (and you do run into dependency problems), the next step would be to set up a separate gemset in RVM.

Comment: Thanx, I followed the same procedure previous but due to some system issue, I was unable to setup it. Anyways thnx..